# Django: What could cause duplicate permissions to be created in the auth_permission table?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a Django app that has been maintained for 4+ years at this point. I joined the team not too long ago. I was getting complaints about group permission issues, and after a lot of inspection, I found out that there were many duplicate permissions.

```
id  |      name      | content_type_id |codename
----+----------------+-----------------+--------
 1      can add x             1          add_x
 2      can add y             2          add_y
 3      can add y             1          add_y
```

I see this kind of behavior in the table where the name/codename is a duplicate of some other valid entry, but then the content_type_id arbitrarily uses some other content_type_id that doesn't relate to it at all. It doesn't happen to every permission, but there are a quite a few in which it is happening. This is a pattern I have observed if the database that this app is connected to has been continually migrated/upgraded over years, then the auth_permission table seems to have this issue of duplicate permissions with random content_type_id. However, when I run the app on my local with the latest version and run the migrations on a fresh db, I get no such issues.

I suspect it has to do something with migrations. Is it possible that at some point in the migrations, a table is created, and then deleted, but the content type for that model doesn't get deleted, and that messes things up?

As a note, this issue does not raise any errors with Django or the db. The only time an issue arises is if we are trying to update the group permissions for a role, there are duplicates all around which makes it hard to find what permissions the group truly has. But no actual errors.

The closest resemblance to this issue I could find was [here](https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox/issues/2624). But there are no proxy models in this app. Does anyone have any ideas that could point me in the right direction as to why this happens and how to potentially resolve it?

Comment: I've had some issues with proxy models and permissions. I had to run custom scripts to generate proper permissions. If your team has rights to run django/db shell in production, it may be a result of a human interaction.

Comment: If your app doesn't have proxy models for now, it doesn't mean it didn't have it in the past. I'd search issue tracking system or ask team members. This could also be a result of some custom migrations without proper reverse code.

Comment: @UnholyRaven Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I have no one to ask at the moment. I've looked through version control and issue tracking, and so far haven't found any instances of proxy model use or custom migrations(yet). However, I have seen a lot Models getting deleted, or Models being changed to inherit from other classes. Could any of those behaviors lead to these permissions issues in present day?